# Index on SQLite child table column being already part of a multi-column unique constraint

Tags: sqlite, indexing, foreign-keys

Given the parent table `p` with the PK column `id` and the child table `c` with the PK columns `foo` and `bar`. `c`.`foo` references `p`.`id`.

1. (Why) Should I create an index on `c`.`foo` or not?
2. And what if `c`.`bar` didn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only strict requirement is on the parent table; the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

There is no such *requirement* for the child table. However, there are cases when the child table is searched for specific key values (e.g., when a parent row is deleted), so

> an index should be created on the child key columns of each foreign key constraint.

If the `foo` column is the first column in the index, then the index can be used to efficiently search for values in `foo`. (There is no difference between explicit and implicit (PK) indices.)